# Extract numbers from Image

Tags: image-processing, ocr, image-segmentation

[image: credit recharge card] 
I have an image for mobile phone credit recharge card and I want to extract the recharge number only (the gray area) as a sequence of number that can be used to recharge the phone directly

This is a sample photo only and cannot be considered as standard, thus the rectangle area may differ in position , in the background and the card also may differ in size .The scratch area may not be fully scratched , the camera's depth and position may differ too . I read a lots and lots of papers on the internet but i can't find any thing that could be interesting and most of papers discuss detection of handwritten numbers .
Any links or algorithms names could be very useful .

Comment: [Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)) is probably the best open-source OCR software around at the moment. Locating the position of the numbers you want to scan in is probably going to be the tricky part at this stage. If the numbers always have a grey background, then perhaps that would be the first thing to look for.

Comment: @Ibrahim , did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @emonik I'm afraid I didn't till now

Comment: @IbrahimAmer Any solution? I tried with tesseract, its not working for scratch cards though

Comment: @Aadam absolutely it won't work with tesseract, as tesseract require that you already segmented the characters/digits. Unfortunately I didn't try any further, so I have no solution tell now, but when I found one I'll share it for sure :))

Answer (score 3):

You can search the papers on [vehicle plate number detection](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2009&q=vehicle%20plate%20number%20detection&hl=en&as_sdt=0,33) with machine learning methods. Basically you need to extract the number first, you may use sobel filter to extract the vertical edges , then threshold (binary image) and morphologic operations (remove blank spaces between each vertical edge line, and connect all regions that have a high number of edges). Finally retrieve the contour and fill in the connected components with mask.

After you extract the numbers , you can use machine learning method such as neural network and svm to recognize them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice .. Do you know where i can find how algorithm for digit recognition ??

Comment: have a try: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=plate+numeral+recognition+algorithm&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C33&as_ylo=2012

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `GRAY` part from image and then Use `Tesseract`(OCR) to extract the text written on the gray image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not find the algorithm to read from the image on the internet. Nobody will disclose that. I think, if you are a hardcore programmer you can crack that using your own code. I tried from the screenshots where the fonts were clearer and the algorithm was simple. For this, the algorithm should be complex since you are reading from photo source instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

Load the image.

Select the digits ( By contour finding and applying constraints on area and height of letters to avoid false detections). This will split the image and thus modularise the OCR operation you want to perform.

A simple K - nearest neighbour algorithm for performing the identification and classification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the end goal was just to make a bot, you could probably pull the text directly from the app rather than worrying about OCR, but if you want to learn more about machine learning and you haven't done them already the MNIST and CIFAR-10 datasets are fantastic places to start.

If you preprocessed your image so that yellow pixels are black and all others are white you would have a much cleaner source to work with.

If you want to push forward with Tesseract for this and the preprocessing isn't enough then you will probably have to retrain it for this font. You will need to prepare a corpus, process it similarly to how you expect your source data to look, and then use something like qt-box-editor to correct the data. This guide should be able to walk you through the basic steps of retraining.