# How to enhance colors and contrast of an noisy image

Tags: image-processing, ocr, image-segmentation, pattern-recognition

I asked this question previously "How to extract numbers from an image"  [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287583/extract-numbers-from-image) and finally i made this step but there is some test cases that leads to awful outputs when i try to recognize digits .. Consider this image as an example

[image]

This image is low contrast (from my POV) i tried to adjust its contrast and the results still unacceptable .I tried also to sharp it then i applied gamma correction but the results still not fair ,so the extracted numbers doesn't recognized well by the classifier

this is the image after (sharpening + gamma)

[image]

Number 4 after separation :

[image]

Could anybody tell me what is the best ideas to solve such a problem ?

Comment: how are you doing the classification?

Comment: @ZawLin I am using MINST database for handwritten digits http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ .The classification is done by using KNN algorithm

Comment: Using a handwritten classifier on printed text is like using a pedestrian classifier on pictures of animals (other than humans).

Comment: i think minst is unsuitable. i suggest you simply collect more real world data and train on them. if that's difficult, you can just generate noisy images from clean fonts. for example, you can generate about a few hundred images with different contrast, blurness, small rotations(-5,5), small shifts, grain noise and retrain. i dont think there is anything you can do about the sharpness. you will just have to improve the classifier

Answer (score 2):

Sharpening is not always the best tool to approach a problem like this. Contrary to what the name implies, sharpening does not "recover" information to add detail and edges back into an image. Instead, sharpening is a class of operations that increase local contrast along edges.

Because your original image is highly degraded, this sharpening operation looks to be adding a lot of noise in, and generally not making anything better.

There is another class of algorithms called "deblurring" algorithms that attempt to actually reconstruct image detail through (much more complex) mathematical models. Some versions of this are blind deconvolution, regularized deconvolution, and Wiener deconvolution.

However, it is important to note that all of these methods are approximations - once image content is lost through an operation such as blurring , it can (almost) never be fully recovered. Also, these methods are generally much more complex.

The best way to handle these situations is make sure that they never happen. Ensure good focus during image capture, use a system with a resolution well suited to your task, control the lighting environment. However, when these methods do not or cannot work, image reconstruction techniques are needed.

Comment: Do you prefer specific algorithm to try with ? Links would be prefered

Answer (score 0):

Your image is blurred, and I suggest you try [wiener deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution). You can assume the point spread function a Gaussian function and observe what's going on with the deconvolution process. Since you do not know the blur kernel in advance, [blind deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_deconvolution) is an alternative.